# Permissions with qBittorrent and Jellyfin

Tags: permissions, users, bittorrent

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with `qbittorrent-nox` and `Jellyfin` as a media server. The quick start guide I followed for qBittorrent recommended having it under a separate user (`qUser`). Jellyfin runs under another user (`mainUser`). The torrent Downloads folder must be owned by `qUser` or else it can't seed or download. When completed, the torrent is owned by `qUser` and has incorrect permissions. Jellyfin needs the files to be under a directory owned by `mainUser` and have the permissions set to 755.
What I have had to do is download the file to a separate qBittorrent owned Downloads dir, use `chown` to change ownership to `mainUser`, run `chmod` to change the permissions to 755 and finally move it to a library directory for Jellyfin. While this works, it is not efficient. What could I do to make this process streamlined to where I could simply have qBitorrent download to a Jellyfin library directory?
Edit: 
Once the torrent is completed, it won't have the correct permissions to be read by Jellyfin. To fix this, I added a small command to execute on torrent completion: `chmod -R 775 "%F/"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a group `media` with both `qUser` and `mainUser` being members of this group:

```
addgroup media
adduser qUser media
adduser mainUser media
```

Set the group of your torrent files to `media` and both processes should be able to read files downloaded by qBittorrent:

```
chgrp -R media path/to/torrents
```

Comment: This solved the issue of qBittorrent not being able to seed or download. Just had to make sure the directory permissions were set to 775.